# Applying Chosen.js to dynamically created dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am having some trouble using the `chosen.js` plugin on my dropdown.There are a few related questions on here that I have worked through but still no luck on my code.

I have 4 dynamically created and populated `select` elements.

```
var dropdownArray = [];

function initDropdown() {

var id = "list";
var classy= "chzn-select";
var html = "";

for ( var idcount = 0; idcount < 4; idcount++) {
    var dropdownHTML = "<select class=\""+classy+"\" id=\"" + id
            + "\" onchange= selectfunc(this) >" +

            "<option selected=\"selected\">Make Selection... </option>" +

            "</select>";

    dropdownArray.push(id);
    html += dropdownHTML;
    id += "0";
}

$("#dropdowns").html(html);
$(".chzn-select").chosen();
};
```

I have tried to use this line to apply `Chosen.js` to the elements by their class name `chzn-select`:

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen();
```

However I am getting the error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'chosen' .
```

Sorry about the messy code, I am new to this.

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you added the script file of `chosen.js` before calling this function

Comment: yeah both chosen.js and chosen.css are included in the html file. This code is in a seperate JS file, also included in the html file. should this make any difference? or does chosen need to be included in this js file.

Comment: no need to be included in this file.  Without using `chosen.js` are you able to see the select dropdown?  I haven't tried for multiple select but used for a single select and it works fine.

Comment: yes all 4 select dropdown elements appear and are populated with options as expected. When logged in console, all have the      chzn-select class assigned but I am still getting the error! thanks for the help any other ideas?

Comment: check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vWKrv/).  If possible create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for your code, so that we can help you.

Comment: never used JSfiddle before, I have had a look at the fiddle you suggested but still cannot apply it to my code. I had a go at putting my own code in a fiddle, but the elements are being populated from data on a private server. I adjusted my script to populate the drop down, but it isn't really working. http://jsfiddle.net/npRx3/11/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your comments, you were trying to create a single SELECT with 4 options using `chosen.js`.  Check out [JSFiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/dxXrh/1/) for result.

From your question, you were trying to create 4 SELECT dynamically using `chosen.js`.  Check out [JSFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/dxXrh/2/).  The reason for error is you missed to point the  right `id` (`dropHolder`).

Answer (score 0):

try this $("#list").trigger("chosen:updated");

got it from [here](https://www.carnaghan.com/knowledge-base/how-to-add-a-new-options-to-jquery-chosen-plugin-dynamically/)